# Error on redeploy of war payara/glassfish server

Tags: java, glassfish, war, payara, redeploy

I've got 2 java web apps which I am deploying in payara 5.2022.2, the first one deploys without any problem and I am able to redeploy whenever I want. The second app, which is practically a copy of the first one, works on deploy on the same domain, but when I try to redeploy it crashes, and deletes al the files inside the payara server.
When I take a look at server.log file I get this 2 lines:

[2022-07-14T08:52:57.906-0300] [Payara 5.2022.2] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=152 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1657799577906] [levelValue: 1000] [[
C:\Users\Desarrollo\Dropbox\Translog Java Desarrollo\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\SAG-1.0]]

[2022-07-14T08:52:57.909-0300] [Payara 5.2022.2] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=1178 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(12)] [timeMillis: 1657799577909] [levelValue: 800] [[
Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: C:\Users\Desarrollo\Dropbox\Translog Java Desarrollo\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\SAG-1.0. Please see server.log for more details. ]]

This is the only error I get. The only way for me to redeploy is to erase all the temporary folders/files it creates and to deploy normally again. Anyone had this kind of problem with payara/glassfish server? Is there any way I can get a more detailed explanation/log of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payara server is inside a Dropbox folder, apparently the auto-sync of Dropbox blocks some files when deploying, causing this peculiar error, although the lack of information of the logs is a problem of glassfish itself. Pausing the auto-sync while deploying solves the problem.